# Color based on value of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web dev and need help. How do I change the color based on the value?

```
<mat-accordion fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="20px" >
      <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z3" *ngFor="let resultSkill of ReportData; let l=index" >
        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="description"  [attr.data-target]="'#happy'+l" >
          <mat-panel-title>
            {{resultSkill.ip_title}}
          </mat-panel-title>
          <span class="button-align2" [innerHTML]="resultSkill.range1"></span>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-description id="happy{{l}}" class="collapse">
        </mat-panel-description>
        <p class="collapse-message"  [innerHTML]="resultSkill.text" style="font-size: 14px;"></p>
        <p class="collapse-message" [innerHTML]="resultSkill.result" style="font-size: 14px;"></p>
        <p class="collapse-message" style="text-align: center; color: #006fd2"><b>How to overcome this?</b></p>
        <p class="collapse-message" [innerHTML]="resultSkill.tips" style="font-size: 14px;"></p>
        <hr class="style5">
      </mat-expansion-panel>
      <br/>
    </mat-accordion>

CSS:
.button-align2{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

[Snapshot of how should it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGY63.png)

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the markup? That seems very odd to have innerHTML wrapped in brackets.

Comment: with pure CSS that's impossible, you would need a javascript function or a dynamic platform like Angular or React to make on the fly changes

Comment: What is the value?

Comment: This is on Angular. I'm learning that as well. As for the value, it should be as shown in the screenshot...

Comment: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-add-a-class-based-on-condition-in-angular/

Comment: I have tried that, but I need to that with string

Comment: How fixed are the things shown in your image? If they are fixed then it's simple CSS to style them. If the innerHTML of them can change then it's at the point of change (using Javascript) that you can change the styling of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a simple JS script inside there. Check out the snippet below or https://codepen.io/ma-henderson/pen/OJRGEqq

```js
const low_color = 'red';
const mid_color = 'yellow';
const high_color = 'green';


const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button2")
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].dataset.skill == 'range1') {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = high_color;
    } else if (buttons[i].dataset.skill == 'range2') {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = mid_color;
    } else {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = low_color;
    }
}
```

```css
.button2{
    margin-right: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="button2" data-skill="range2">Some Text</span>
```

Comment: The question was how to change styling based on innerHTML. Your use of innerHTML (a number) is not the same as in the question.

Comment: you're right. I've changed it now, He'd still need to implement his own range/color scheme though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure CSS and escape the brackets in the selector and use nth-child to specify which element for changing the background color.

```css
[\[innerHTML\]='resultSkill.range1']:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

[\[innerHTML\]='resultSkill.range1']:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<span class="button-align2" [innerHTML]="resultSkill.range1">red</span>
<span class="button-align2" [innerHTML]="resultSkill.range1">orange</span>
```

Comment: There is no two range value, it's one innerHTML which display the various value of range based on input. That's why I don't get any color based on the value if I use inline CSS to set the background color it will display only that color.

Comment: @Silver, I have updated my answer. What is the GENERATED HTML look like? Like when you inspect element.